# MCU wakes up from sleep periodically

Tags: interrupts, sleep, cortex-m4, texas-instruments

I'm facing a weird behavior on SOME boards based upon CC3220SF.

**Scenario**

- I have 20 units of my custom PCB, designed following the Design Reference Guidelines from Texas Instruments and - like they suggest - "copying" the layout from the demo board
- most of them work fine, and they have passed the CE tests

**The issue**

Some of them, instead, wakes up periodically from the hibernation state claiming a GPIO interrupt the reset cause.
This should not happen because I disabled any wakeup policy for GPIO:

```
const PowerCC32XX_ConfigV1 PowerCC32XX_config = {
    .policyInitFxn = &PowerCC32XX_initPolicy,
    .policyFxn = &PowerCC32XX_sleepPolicy,
    .enterLPDSHookFxn = NULL,
    .resumeLPDSHookFxn = NULL,
    .enablePolicy = false, 
    .enableGPIOWakeupLPDS = false,
    .enableGPIOWakeupShutdown = false,
    .enableNetworkWakeupLPDS = false,
    .wakeupGPIOSourceLPDS = PRCM_LPDS_GPIO13,
    .wakeupGPIOTypeLPDS = PRCM_LPDS_RISE_EDGE,
    .wakeupGPIOFxnLPDS = NULL,
    .wakeupGPIOFxnLPDSArg = 0,
    .wakeupGPIOSourceShutdown = 0, 
    .wakeupGPIOTypeShutdown = PRCM_HIB_RISE_EDGE,
    .ramRetentionMaskLPDS = PRCM_SRAM_COL_1 | PRCM_SRAM_COL_2 | PRCM_SRAM_COL_3 | PRCM_SRAM_COL_4,
    .keepDebugActiveDuringLPDS = true,
    .ioRetentionShutdown = PRCM_IO_RET_GRP_1,
    .pinParkDefs = parkInfo,
    .numPins = sizeof(parkInfo) / sizeof(PowerCC32XX_ParkInfo)
};
```

I call Power_shutdown(0, 300000); but when MCU wakes up I find:

```
PRCMSysResetCauseGet() == PRCM_HIB_EXIT 
PRCMHibernateWakeupCauseGet() == PRCM_HIB_WAKEUP_CAUSE_GPIO.
```

**Test I've made**

As said this not happen to all boards. So, at first, I was looking for something hardware. I set up a test firmware:

```
void ApplicationTask(void)
{
    InitSimplelink(ROLE_STA);
    ledOn(); // turn on a LED so I can easily see when the MCU is active

    for (;;)
    {
        Platform_Sleep(5000);
        powerShutdown(300000);
    }
}
```

The "reference" board (one that works fine) exhibits the expected behavior: the LED turns on for 5 s, then the MCU hibernates for 300 s (I also changed this time - no matter).

One of the DUT board wakes up every 2 seconds, while another every 20 seconds at room temperature. Changing the temperature the interval changes a lot: at about 40 °C the interval is shorter, about 4 s. At about 10 °C is about 39 s.

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on the "working" boards - even changing the temperature.

Furthermore, I tried to read the Slow Clock Counter (the clock that runs even in hibernation state) and it seems consistent with the real time - i.e. it doesn't change (a lot?) with temperature.

**Question**

The question is quite straightforward: what do you recommend in such a situation to deeply understand what's happening?

### UPDATE

**Using a very thin nozzle to my hot-air gun, I was able to heat each IC on my board. No effect at all until I went to the MCU itself: just after applying warm air to it the interval dropped instantly from 22 s to 1 s.**

Schematic

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

Comment: Please provide circuit diagram of your board (even if it just copies the reference circuit diagram), and then image of the board from both sides. You explanation sounds like there's some marginal state, or some component misbehaves. It also could be a bad contact.

Comment: Right now I can upload the schematics only. Please note the boards were assembled by a PCB Assembly Manufacturer.

Comment: DO you have a link to the document that details that feature.

Comment: Does the MCU reset out of sleep or does it keep its RAM contents through the sleep period?

Comment: @Trevor_G Chapter 15 of the Technical Reference Manual: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru465/swru465.pdf

Comment: And Chapter 15 of DriverLib User Guide: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu298d/spmu298d.pdf

Comment: @filo: when the MCU enters in hibernation mode (not LPDS) the RAM contents is not saved. Only the 32 kHz Slow Clock runs and the GPIO interrupts (if enabled, I hope...)

Comment: Can you distinguish a wake-up from a crash/hardfault? If the MCU starts from the reset than it can be either of those. You don't know without extra diagnostic code.

Comment: I should: PRCMSysResetCauseGet() returns the reset cause and in this case is PRCM_HIB_EXIT. Please note that into hibernation mode NO code is executed. The main oscillator is also shut down.

Comment: Question update with a new important test.